# Can MAX485 be connected to SN75176 for RS485 communication?

Tags: communication, rs485

In one side I have an SN75176 and the other side is MAX485. Can both be connected for RS485 communication?

Comment: the basic idea is if they are both RS485 compliant they can talk to each other. Be careful with polarity, biasing and termination however (IIRC they are both no fault tolerant so if the line is not driven the signal is dubious)

Answer (score 2):

They are both RS-485 transceivers.

Assumption is that two RS-485 transceivers can be connected together for communication.